# Appium does not start in Mac system

Tags: testing, automation, appium, appium-ios

Im getting the below error while click `Launch` button:

> "Appium will not work if used or installed with sudo. Please
>   rerun/install as a non-root user. If you had to install Appium using
>   `sudo npm install -g appium`, the solution is to reinstall Node using
>   a method (Homebrew, for example) that doesn't require sudo to install
>   global npm packages."

Comment: Did you install using `sudo`?

Comment: @orde - Yes installed

Comment: @VelanAssociate is ur issue sovled?

Comment: Well, the error message says to *not* install via `sudo`.

Comment: Yes  karthick23 my issues solved